# Problem with Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]

Tags: ubuntu

When I run

```
wget -r --user "user" --password "pass" ftp://ftpadd/opt/oss -A date "--date"='yesterday' +'%Y%m%d'
```

I get this error :

> wget: unrecognized option '--date=yesterday' 
>   Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]... 
>   Try `wget --help' for more options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the date command to filter for filenames that contain that date, you can use bash command substitution by wrapping your date command inside $()

eg:

```
wget -r --user "user" --password "pass" ftp://ftpadd/opt/oss -A "$(date --date='yesterday' +'%Y%m%d')"
```

Comment: ** are required to select desired characters in a file name

Comment: there is no problem in getting date, the problem is using --date between * *, maybe ! I don't know exactly

Comment: Apologies. I misunderstood your question. Have edited the answer and code example to include command substitution which should do what you need

Comment: I tested this with some changes *$(date --date='yesterday' +'%Y%m%d')* and it worked. thank you